# load image url in kotlin does not show the image

Tags: android, kotlin

l am new in kotlin and I have an API which returns JSON and his working fine and I would like to load an Image from a URL in list view .but the problem is the images is not showing when lunching app , only the data json text show in list view .

my code in list adapte :

```
class ListAdapte (val context: MainActivity, val list: ArrayList<FlightShdu>): BaseAdapter() {

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false)

        val code = view.findViewById(R.id.code_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val LogoAriline = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
        val imgUri = "https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/"+code+"_logo0.png"

        code.text = list[position].logo
        Picasso.get().load(imgUri).into(LogoAriline)



        return view as View
    }
```

Comment: Try using RecyclerView instead. Better performance.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce do you have example please ? l am new in kotlin language

Comment: you can add `.setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` to get more info on why the image doesn't load.

Comment: @ZUNJAE when l use .Picasso.with(context) in kotlin l got unresolved reference with

Comment: @pabloescobar which version of Picasso do u have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `with` property to pass the context to picasso.

```
   Picasso.with(context)
     .load(imgUri)
     .into(LogoAriline);
```

Answer (score 1):

You put your `code` (`AppCompatTextView`) into your url. 
Kotlin call `code.toString()` in that case. But that's no what you try to do.

You probably want to get the text into your `AppCompatTextView` with **code.text**:

```
val imgUri = "https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/${code.text}_logo0.png"
```

or (this is the same)

```
val imgUri = "https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/static/images/data/operators/" + code.text + "_logo0.png"
```